# LaTeX beamer free-flowing two column?

Tags: latex, beamer

So in standard LaTeX, there is \twocolumn, where I can just type text, and it'll go down the left side of the page, then continue at the top of the right side of the page.

Now, I know that inside of a Beamer frame, I can manually create two columns, of various width, with text in them -- however, is there a way to have the text freely flow from one column to the next? [I.e. I want to say "this text goes in these two columns; and have beamer figure out which goes into which column].

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could try with the [multicol package](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/multicol.html). However, with all the magic that Beamer does, it's hard to tell whether this will work.

Comment: It works ok provided you don't try to squeeze in too much text.